# Subset until the condition is met (including it) by group data.table

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I would like to subset my data.table by doing this : by grouping `id` and `group` take the 1st row to the row when the condition is met. It means that if the condition is met at the 3rd row, I would like to keep the rows 1,2 and 3.

Example of the data :

```
    id time group
 1:  1    0     1
 2:  1   20     1
 3:  1    0     2
 4:  1   40     2
 5:  2    0     1
 6:  2   35     1
 7:  2   50     1
 8:  3    0     1
 9:  3   10     1
10:  3   20     1
11:  3    0     2
12:  3   25     2
13:  3   45     2
```

The condition is : `time > 30` so the expected results will be :

```
    id time group
 1:  1    0     2
 2:  1   40     2
 3:  2    0     1
 4:  2   35     1
 5:  3    0     2
 6:  3   25     2
 7:  3   45     2
```

I tried : `df[1:which(time >30)[1], .SD, by = .(id, group)]`

but it returns :

```
   id group time
1:  1     1    0
2:  1     1   20
3:  1     2    0
4:  1     2   40
```

Data :

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), 
               time = c(0, 20, 0, 40, 0, 35, 50, 0, 10, 20, 0, 25, 45), 
               group = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)), .Names = c("id", 
                                                                             "time", "group"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                                  "data.frame"))
```

**UPDATE** showing an expected behaviour of akrun's answer with another dataset :

Data :

```
> dftest
     patientid groupe arret dateConsult lag_dateConsult temps abst temps_cum
1: 0303H233457      2     1  2011-10-05            <NA>     0    1         0
2: 0303H233457      2     1  2011-11-09      2011-10-05    35    1        35
3: 0303H233457      2     1  2011-12-21      2011-11-09    42    1        77
4: 0303H233457      2     1  2012-01-30      2011-12-21    40    1       117
5: 0303H233457      2     1  2012-04-18      2012-01-30    79    1       196
6: 0303H233457      2     1  2012-08-27      2012-04-18   131    1       327
7: 0303H233457      4     1  2012-11-19            <NA>     0    1         0
8: 0303H233457      4     1  2013-01-07      2012-11-19    49    1        49
```

What I get :

```
> dftest[dftest[, .I[seq(which(temps_cum > 30))], .(patientid, groupe)]$V1]
     patientid groupe arret dateConsult lag_dateConsult temps abst temps_cum
1: 0303H233457      2     1  2011-10-05            <NA>     0    1         0
2: 0303H233457      2     1  2011-11-09      2011-10-05    35    1        35
3: 0303H233457      2     1  2011-12-21      2011-11-09    42    1        77
4: 0303H233457      2     1  2012-01-30      2011-12-21    40    1       117
5: 0303H233457      2     1  2012-04-18      2012-01-30    79    1       196
6: 0303H233457      4     1  2012-11-19            <NA>     0    1         0
7: 0303H233457      4     1  2013-01-07      2012-11-19    49    1        49
```

Results expected :

```
     patientid groupe arret dateConsult lag_dateConsult temps abst temps_cum
1: 0303H233457      2     1  2011-10-05            <NA>     0    1         0
2: 0303H233457      2     1  2011-11-09      2011-10-05    35    1        35
3: 0303H233457      4     1  2012-11-19            <NA>     0    1         0
4: 0303H233457      4     1  2013-01-07      2012-11-19    49    1        49
```

Data :

```
structure(list(patientid = c("0303H233457", "0303H233457", "0303H233457", 
                             "0303H233457", "0303H233457", "0303H233457", "0303H233457", "0303H233457"
), groupe = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4), arret = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                 1, 1, 1, 1), dateConsult = structure(c(15252, 15287, 15329, 15369, 
                                                                                        15448, 15579, 15663, 15712), class = "Date"), lag_dateConsult = structure(c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                    15252, 15287, 15329, 15369, 15448, NA, 15663), class = "Date"), 
temps = c(0, 35, 42, 40, 79, 131, 0, 49), abst = c(1, 1, 
                                                   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), temps_cum = c(0, 35, 77, 117, 196, 327, 
                                                                                    0, 49)), .Names = c("patientid", "groupe", "arret", "dateConsult", 
                                                                                                        "lag_dateConsult", "temps", "abst", "temps_cum"), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                                                                    "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: If you meant `dftest[dftest[, .I[seq(which(temps_cum > 30)[1])], .(patientid, groupe)]$V1]` it works for me

Comment: @akrun Yeah that's what I was expecting. However I got this error on my full dataset : `Error in seq.default(which(temps_cum > 30)[1]) : 
  'from' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite`, do you what what can cause this ?

Comment: Please check if there are only one element per group and that one is not qualifying for the `temps_cum > 30`, in that case, perhaps, you can use an `if/else` condition `dftest[, if(any(temps_cum > 30)) .I[seq(which(temps_cum > 30)[1])], .(patientid, groupe)]`

Comment: @akrun Yeah I checked it before running your answer : `summary` is telling me the `min` is 2 (when I count by groups with `.N`) and `range` is returning : `0 917`. Adding the `if`corrects the error so thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After grouping by 'id', 'group', get the row index where 'time' is greater than 30, and subset the rows

```
df1[df1[, .I[seq(which(time > 30))], .(id, group)]$V1]
```

---

If we also need up till the last row where 'time' is greater than 30

```
df1[df1[, .I[seq(tail(which(time > 30), 1))], .(id, group)]$V1]
#   id time group
#1:  1    0     2
#2:  1   40     2
#3:  2    0     1
#4:  2   35     1
#5:  2   50     1
#6:  3    0     2
#7:  3   25     2
#8:  3   45     2
```

Comment: works like a charm as always, I will accept the answer asap

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I have a strange behaviour with my real data and the results are not expected, will te be possible that you check with a subset on which it doesn't work as expected ?

Comment: @MbrMbr  Could you please update your post with a small example that shows the bugs

Comment: I updated the post. Tell me if you have the same problem or not.